# Virtual playback device with remapped channels

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a working 7.1 speaker setup, under pulse audio.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. while keeping my current physical playback device and speakers as is,
2. add a new virtual device that I can switch to using pavucontrol etc.,
3. which will be a 2.1 audio output (downmixing ?)
4. remapped to two of the right side speakers plus the subwoofer

I think the channel mapping should be something like this:

- FL + SL + RL + FC*0.5 -> SR   // this will be my new "Left" speaker
- FR + SR + RR + FC*0.5 -> FR   // this will be my new "Right" speaker
- LFE -> LFE

Any pointers on how to do it?

7.1 setup - what I have

```
[FL]   [FC]   [FR]
         [LFE]
[SL]          [SR]
        ↑
[RL]    o     [RR]
       /|\
       / \
```

2.1 virtual setup - what I want

```
[  ]   [  ]   [R ]
         [LFE]      ← ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
[  ]          [L ]

[  ]          [  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it, using:

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=RemappedStereo sink_properties="device.description='RemappedStereo'" remix=no master=MASTER_DEVICE channels=9 channel_map=front-left,side-left,rear-left,front-center,front-right,side-right,rear-right,front-center,lfe master_channel_map=side-right,side-right,side-right,side-right,front-right,front-right,front-right,front-right,lfe
```

- `master` is your audio device and can be obtained using `pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:'`
- `channels` is the number of "remapped pairs" - eg. in this case, `front-center` is counted twice because it is mapped to both output speakers
- `channel_map` is the list of *source* channels
- `master_channel_map` is the list of *destination* channels (1 to 1 with `channel_map`)